# Prevent PHP from automatically escaping returned string?

Tags: php, markdown

I have a function that returns a string of HTML code for a jQuery plugin, parsed using [PHP Markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/):

```
function awesome_function() {
  $html = Markdown('# Hello World!');
  return $html;
}
```

... but PHP (5.3.2) returns this:

```
"<h1>Hello World!<\/h1>\n"
```

... instead of what I want, which is this:

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

How do I get it to return the non-escaped HTML value? Changing `return` to `echo` works, but then I have the `return` status of the function returned as well (true|false|null), which I don't want.

---

EDIT: Not sure if it's relevant, but I just realized that I probably should have mentioned that my function is a public function for a class, as such:

```
class Awesome {
  public function awesome_function() { /* ... */ }
}
```

---

For @fredrick:

```
$('.edit').editable('/controllers/awesome_controller.php', {
  id: 'identifier',
  name: 'content',
  submitdata: { action: 'awesome_function' },
  submit: 'Ok',
  cancel: 'Cancel',
  loadurl: '/controllers/awesome_controller.php',
  loaddata: { action: 'load_original_markdown' }
});
```

Comment: what are you doing whit the return value? are you just echoing it like: echo awesome_function(); and it adds the slashes?

Comment: It's returning the html for a jQuery plugin, to inject content on the page. I'm using it with this plugin: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Comment: ok, but how does the code look where you insert awesome_function() into you js / html?

Comment: Just like the plugin example. I'll include the JS in the question for you to look at.

Comment: hmm, can I have a look inside awesome_controller.php as well? After that I'll hopefully wont ask for more code =)

Comment: Ahhh! You are so right! My homebrew controller was encoding it as JSON... man I'm thick sometimes. Thanks for the sleuthing. ;)

Comment: that was what I was thinking! :D (JSON, not the thick part)

Comment: @fredrick - Haha, oh well. Say, would you mind posting your suggestion about the JSON encoding as an answer to the question, so I can mark it as answered? I'm kinda OCD about these things... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we figured out, you have something like this in your code:

```
$awesome = new Awesome();
echo json_encode($awesome->awesome_function());
```

json_encode will add slashes to the output, and when you echo instead of returning from awesome_function, two values will be echoed, the HTML, and also the json_encoded response from the awesome_function (true|false|null).

Answer (score 2):

Try using `stripslashes()` after you use `Markdown`:

```
function awesome_function() {
  $html = Markdown('# Hello World!');
  $html = stripslashes($html);
  return $html;
}
```

Read about it here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: Markdown doesn't add the slashes, PHP's `return` does. I've verified this.

Comment: Thanks this is the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to magic quotes - you can read about here http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: I've disabled magic_quotes (`magic_quotes_runtime = Off` in my php.ini file, and phpconfig() confirms it's off), and the problem is still there.

Comment: This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.
magic_quotes_runtime